# Show div based on input value then hide if unchecked

Tags: jquery, if-statement, this, bind, unbind

Hi all I have a survey that when a box is checked it displays an answer based upon which answer you selected. I got this working and all, but am running into trouble when someone unchecks a box I want the div to go back to being hidden.

Here is the code I have written:

```
// if else statement for question 6
$("input[name='name_6[]']").bind("click", function(event){

    // If the value is equal to 25 or less show response 1
    if ($(this).val() <= 25) {
        $("#q6response1").slideDown('fast');
        $("#q6response2").hide();

}  // If the value is equal to 26 show response 2
    else if ($(this).val() == 26) {
        $("#q6response2").slideDown('fast');
        $("#q6response1").hide();

}
});
```

I tried using unbind and :checked, false and nothing seems to work. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
// if else statement for question 6
$("input[name='name_6[]']").change(function(event){

    // If the value is equal to 25 or less show response 1
    if ($(this).val() <= 25) {
        $("#q6response1").slideDown('fast');
        $("#q6response2").hide();

    }  // If the value is equal to 26 show response 2
    else if ($(this).val() == 26) {
        $("#q6response2").slideDown('fast');
        $("#q6response1").hide();

  }
});
```